# navigator.getBattery() not working on S3 static website

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, batterylevel

Normally in Chrome I can get the battery level by doing something like

```
navigator.getBattery().then((battery) => {
    console.log(battery.level)
})
```

This works fine when testing with a local file and on other websites, however, when I try to do this on an [S3 static website](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html) it gives me this error: `Uncaught TypeError: navigator.getBattery is not a function`. This is in Chrome which [supports the getBattery method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getBattery#browser_compatibility). The only difference is that it is on an S3 static website. Why is this method not found when hosting on S3?

Comment: Is the js file served under a secure context? MDN says - *must be served over https:// or wss:// URLs*

Comment: @Rayon it's not, it looks like https is not supported by S3 static websites, so this must be the issue

Comment: You may pass it through any CDN like CloudFront etc.